# Is there a way to redirect a python dependency to the /usr/bin/env python?

Tags: python, pip

## Issue

An application bundles in Python 3.8 and has a dependency on its relative path of <application_path/bin/Python/Python-3.8/lib/libpython3.8> which is used to run python scripts.

I would like to redirect that usage to the current python being used so the application is not so big when redistributing it. (The python version is locked above 3.8 on the systems using this app)

The idea is that the path is a symlink to the output of `which python`.

Is this possible? It needs to work in venvs as well.

## Question

This does not work with a symlink on my dev system, how can I make essentially a symlink point to whatever python executable is being used on the target systems?

## Attempts

### Script

libpython3.8.so:

```
#!/bin/bash
python "$@"
```

#### Error

`File too short`

Comment: "Is this possible?" Did you try it?

Comment: This is possible on my system; however, I don't know how to enable this application to "know" the location of the python for the systems it's on. Edited the post accordingly.

Comment: You can obtain the path of the Python executable with "sys.executable". Is this what you want?

Comment: Turns out the path to the executable was not what was needed, it was a link to the actual python .so that was needed.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the path to the .so file was needed, not the python executable.
In answer to this question, the script I posted worked.